# Write Pandas dataframe data to CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, cx-oracle

I am trying to write a pipeline to bring oracle database table data to aws.

It only takes a few ms to fill the dataframe, but when I try to write the dataframe to a csv-file it takes more than 2 min to write 10000 rows. In addition, one of the column's datatypes is cx_oracle lob type.

I thought this meant that it must take time to write data. So I converted the data to categorical data. But then the operation will take more memory space. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to optimize this process?

```python
query = 'select * from tablename'
cursor.execute(query)
iter_idx = 0
while True:
    results = cursor.fetchmany()
    if not results:
        break
    iter_idx += 1
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.columns = field['source_field_names']
    rec_count = df.shape[0]
    t_rec_count += rec_count

    file = generate_micro_file()
    print('memory usage : \n', df.info(memory_usage='deep'))

    # sd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
    df.to_csv(file, encoding=str(encoding_type), header=False, index=False, escapechar='\\',chunksize=arraysize)
```

code output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the data access side, there is room for improvement by optimizing the fetching of rows across the network. Either by:

- passing a large `num_rows` value to `fetchmany()`, see the cx_Oracle doc on [`Cursor.fetchmany()`[(https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.fetchmany).
- or increasing the value of `Cursor.arraysize`.

Your question didn't explain enough about your LOB usage.  See the sample [return_lobs_as_strings.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/8.3.0/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py) for optimizing fetches.

See the cx_Oracle documentation [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Is there a particular reason to spend the overhead of converting to a Pandas dataframe?  Why not write directly using the csv module?

Maybe something like this:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "select * from all_objects where rownum <= 100000"
    cursor.arraysize = 10000
    with open("testwrite.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outputfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile, lineterminator="\n")
        results = cursor.execute(sql)
        writer.writerows(results)
```

You should benchmark and choose the best solution.